# Склонение названий книг

Tags: грамотная-речь

На соседнем форуме "Математика" мне пришлось сослаться на книгу "Физики шутят". Я написала так: **в "Физики шутят"**. Хотела, правда, написать **в "Физиках шутят"**, но это уж совсем неправильно. Или нет?

Можно ли подобным образом употреблять название без родового слова "книга"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocentI, вы бы почетче вопрос ставили.

> > > Я написала так: в "Физики шутят".

Так можно. Слово "книга" необходимо в устной речи в аудитории, где об этой книге не знают. Среди физиков-математиков старшего возраста, где где книжка давно стала культовой, думаю, необязательно. В письменном же тексте это не так строго, кавычки берут на себя указание на то, что это название.

> > > Хотела, правда, написать в "Физиках шутят", но это уж совсем неправильно.

А так, естественно, нельзя.

Comment: behemothus, подскажите, пожалуйста, как ВЫ цитату вставляете?

Comment: Попробуйте знак > в начале абзаца:  

> это цитата

Comment: Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 0):

Нет, нельзя. Если бы книга называлась  просто "Физики" - тогда да. А так, прочитайте, что у Вас получается: "Физиках шутят" - это по-русски? Все-таки подлежащее должно стоять в именительном падеже! Что касается слова книга, то его лучше употребить. Хотя бы потому, что так легче воспринимается смысл фразы.

Comment: Я поняла, почему мне хотелось сказать "в "Физиках шутят"".  
Ведь говорим же мы "в Фихтенгольце" или "в Демидовиче", хотя оба - люди, авторы учебников, и в них быть ничего не может, по крайней мере, того, что имеется в виду (задачи, теоремы).  
Так же и "физики" приобрели переносное значение как имя широко известной книги. Только слово "шутят" немного мешает.